Prompt User to Select Power Query Data Source
I'd like to set up some VBA so that users are prompted to select 2 different filepaths, and those files are then set as the source in two different powerquery tables. I'd like to just set it so the powerquery code can refer to a variant defined by the VBA instead of referring to the named cell in the excel sheet. Any solutions?
My current workaround is that I have some VBA that prompts users to select select a file path and then another file path. Those filepaths are then set as two different cell values on a worksheet. I've named those cells ("PopManFilePath" and "ClinComFilePath").  The source in my powerquery is set as those named cells.
See VBA below:
Sub FileSelectandRefreshQueries()
    Dim answerpop As Integer
    answerpop = MsgBox("Please select your population management file in the following window. It must be a .csv file.", vbOKCancel, "Instructions")
    
    If answerpop = vbOK Then
        Dim PopManFileName As Variant
         PopManFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Please select population management file")
     
            If PopManFileName <> False Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilePaths").Range("B1").Value = PopManFileName
            End If
    End If
    
    Dim answerclin As Integer
    answerclin = MsgBox("Please select your clinical complexity file in the following window. It must be a .csv file.", vbOKCancel, "Instructions")
    
        If answerclin = vbOK Then
        Dim ClinComName As Variant
         ClinComName = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", Title:="Please select clinical complexity file")
        
            If ClinComName <> False Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilePaths").Range("B2").Value = ClinComName
            End If
        End If

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub

And this is my very simple powerquery code to set the source in one of my tables:
let
  LocalPath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PopManFilePath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
  Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(LocalPath),[Delimiter="#(tab)", Encoding=1200, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),

I feel like there must be a better way to do this that doesn't involve writing the file paths into a cell.

The only way that I know we can avoid using an Excel Range is to update the formula.
Sub UpdateFileQuery(FilePath As String)
    Const QueryName As String = "TestQuery"
    Dim Query As WorkbookQuery
    Set Query = ThisWorkbook.Queries(QueryName)
    Query.Formula = "let" & vbNewLine & _
        "Source = Folder.Files(" & Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34) & ")" & vbNewLine & _
        "in" & vbNewLine & _
        "   Source"
    Query.Refresh
End Sub

There are many ways that you could improve the User Experience (UX).

Change the default directory before calling Application.GetOpenFilename
Eliminate the first MsgBox
If you already know the correct folder, populate List or Combo Boxes with the file names
Create a Userform to fetch the files

